# Mail service for family with heterogeneous background and use

Tags: email, web-services

I want a mail adress (and corresponding mailboxes, each having its own login/password) for each of the N members of my family, with 3 < N < 12 (it will evolve with time).

I therefore searching for a (paid) webservice.

### What i already have

I have a domain i pay yearly, and since it's my last name, i want to use it as domain for the mail adresses (to get, for each family member, firstname@lastname.net).
I also have a personal server that could help ; although i do not have the will, time nor knowledge to run myself a mail server.

### Usages

My family is mostly composed of non-tech users, but some (including me) needs their environment and will not use the service if not reachable from it. The features we need are therefore:

- access via webmail, for non-tech peoples
- interface with desktop mail clients and PGP encryption, like thunderbird+enigmail or mutt, for those like me who needs their specific environment.
- if possible, with PGP encryption available (to promote good habits), and Free/open-source (i'm an idealist)
- support family usage : few thousands mails sent/received per week at most, around 3GB of memory per human,…
- privacy, guarantees that there is no usage of personal data, etc.
- price at most of 50€/account/year

### What i tried

I tried Protonmail, which provide support for custom domains, but:

- only for one account, or
- for multiple accounts, but with a way too high price for a family usage (75€/human/year)

Also, protonmail does not support integration with my environment (linux, thunderbird, i already have a PGP key and do not want to share it).
This is a no-go for me.

### What i know

There is a lot of alternatives that *could* match with my needs. Since i discovered protonmail flaws only after paying a plan, i though i could use some indication from community before testing other solutions.

Comment: Can't write a full answer right now, but consider getting web hosting from a hosting company that uses cPanel and use the email service that comes with that.